# Python voxelfuse can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, voxel

I'm trying to generate a .vox represantation of my Prison Architect save file. I'm using a library called voxelfuse to generate the voxels and for some reason the union() method gives me a `can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`
Here's my code:

```
cubes = []

for tile in tiles:
    cubes.append(cuboid((6,18,6),(tile['x'],1,tile['y']),2))

finalmodel = cubes[0]

for cube in cubes:
    if cube != cubes[0]:
        finalmodel = finalmodel.union(cube)
            

mesh1 = Mesh.fromVoxelModel(finalmodel)
mesh1.export(filename + '.vox')
```

What confuses me the most is the fact that variables `finalmodel` and `cube` that are used as arguments in the method aren't ints or strings, but instead are `VoxelModel`

And just in case `tile['x']` and `tile['y']` are ints that come from the parsed savefile.

I can't figure out whether I have made a mistake while creating the Voxelmodels or there is something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Where is your `filename` defined? What about the error message is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering `tiles` is read from a file I believe the problem may be that `tile['x']` and `tile['y']` are strings and not integers. Try to transform them before passing them as arguments:

```py
for tile in tiles:
    cubes.append(cuboid((6,18,6),(int(tile['x']),1,int(tile['y'])),2))
```

Comment: That worked ! Thank you! Yeah, probably should have doublechecked given that i used regex to find them.